# Dynamically creating Table Layout Panel takes too long

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a WinForms application in C#. I initially have a Table Layout Panel which I populate with dynamically created buttons, one for each cell. This works well, and quite fast. During the program execution, I have to clear this Table Layout Panel and repopulate it, pretty much with the same display, but more buttons (twice the number from the initial table). The problem is that this process takes a lot of time (over 10 seconds). Am I doing something wrong? This is the code:

```
buttonTable.Controls.Clear();
buttonTable.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
buttonTable.RowCount = GetNoOfLines();
buttonTable.ColumnCount = GetNoOfLines();

for (int z = 1; z <= GetNoOfLines(); z++)
{
    buttonTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25));
    buttonTable.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25));
}

for (int i = 1; i <= GetNoOfLines(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= GetNoOfLines(); j++)
    {
        FieldButton tempButton = new FieldButton(i, j, GetNoOfLines());
        tempButton.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(OnFieldButtonClicked);

        buttonTable.Controls.Add(tempButton, j - 1, i - 1);
     }
 }
```

Note: `FieldButton` is a class derived from `Button`, to which I've added two `int's`, nothing special about it. Also, the buttons are added correctly to the table. Thanks!

Comment: What does `GetNoOfLines()` do and is it necessary to call it over and over?

Comment: It's a function that returns an int. I don't think the problem is within it, but within the table creation.

Comment: Maybe so.  But if GetNoOfLines() remains the same throughout the loop, then the result should be stored in a variable instead to reduce cost.

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course, but the problem persists even with the value stored and used locally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had problems with TableLayoutPanel performance until I read [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/373b5c93-9646-4a84-8ac4-513d277ec1d6/?prof=required) and created a custom control that set the DoubleBuffered property.

```
public class DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel :TableLayoutPanel
{
    public DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Try that control instead of the standard TableLayoutPanel. I second the advice to suspend and resume layout while you're populating the table.

Answer (score 2):

Detach buttonTable from the form and attach just after you are done adding controls to it. Works fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` before and after your code adding the buttons to decrease the time taken to repaint the buttons. This should decrease some time

Comment: It doesn't decrease the time at all.